# triple boot and all of my system cannot connet to the network after ubuntu16.04 suspend

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu16.04 , Windows and OSX installed on my Dell XPS 13. All of them work fine until today. After Ubuntu suspend, I can't connect to the internet, even after rebooting the system. What's worse, I find all of my three system cannot connect to the network ether either.

I can find the WIFI near me, but I cannot connect to them.
[Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41fpK.jpg)
[Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPn34.jpg)

here's my network info:

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 03
   serial: c4:8e:8f:f4:48:77
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
  *-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: virbr0-nic
   serial: 52:54:00:1f:2e:04
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Any tips is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Start by shutting down instead of just rebooting. Check your UEFI settings also because the Ethernet appears as disabled. . Reboot your router. If after all this the problem persists contact your tech support because something is defective.

Comment: This may not work, but it worth giving it a try. Open terminal and type `sudo service network-manager restart`.  By the way, The problem could be from your bios settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but all of these hint seams not work:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. I disabled and  enabled the network card in bios then reboot and everything's fine now!
Thanks for comments above. I hope this can help other people who is in same trouble.